# Selecting a specific database in odbc c#

Tags: c#, database, odbc, database-schema

I've been looking for a while now and I haven't found anything on this.  I'm trying to get the column names of all the tables from a SPECIFIC database through ODBC.
I have been trying to use`conn.GetSchema("Tables")` and `conn.GetSchema("Columns")`.  The issue is that it returns all the tables inside my server.
I have multiple database (i.e database ''Food'', ''Cooks'', etc.) and I'm trying to get Tables and Columns from one specific database (i.e only ''Food'').
My connection string does specify the right database, but it seems to be ignored when I use `GetSchema`.

Anybody can help?  Here is the code I'm using right now

```
            DataTable tables = conn.GetSchema("Tables");
            DataTable columns = conn.GetSchema("Columns");

            foreach (DataRow r in tables.Rows)
            {
                string name = r["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
            }
            foreach (DataRow row in columns.Rows)
            {
                string name = row["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString();

                if (!allMongoInfo.ContainsKey(name)) //Dictionary
                    issuesImpala.Add (name);          
            }
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I'm using the Cloudera ODBC Driver for Impala

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this could work with your ODBC driver, but this is the way to get just a single table and/or the columns of that table using the `GetSchema` method of an `OdbcConnection`

```
using (OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection("......"))
{ 
    con.Open();
    var schema = con.GetSchema("Tables", new string[] {null, null, "yourTableName"});
    var cols = con.GetSchema("Columns", new string[] {null, null, "yourTableName"});
}
```

This overload of the GetSchema method accepts an array of strings that represents **restrictions** on the returned data.
You can learn more about the values for the **restrictions** parameter in this article on MSDN [Schema Restrictions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716722(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: But where do I input the specific Database?

Comment: This is specified in the connection string. I have omitted here because I don't have the details, but it should be written replacing the dots in the using statement

Comment: However I have no experience with that database, so perhaps, it should be specified using the restriction for the CATALOG (see the link posted above)